# iOS/xcode - How can I open a new storyboard from UITabBarController and keep the UITabBar from disappearing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have been working to link multiple storyboards off of a single`UITabBarController`.  I have it working where I can get the new storyboard to open and present the initial `UIViewController`, just the `UITabBar` disappears when it opens the new storyboard.

Here is the code I am using to switch to the new storyboard:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if ( [viewController isMemberOfClass:[ProfileRedirectViewController class]] )
    {
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Profile" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileTableViewController"];


        [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:false];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I had been playing around with the`navigationController` version, but it would just do nothing and resulted in a dead click and no errors in log.  I have been searching for an answer to this for a bit and maybe i've been going down some wrong paths.  I am new to xcode so I could very well be missing something obvious or using wonky search terms to find help.

The `UITabBar` works fine when we are navigating to any of the other views within the main storyboard, it's only when I move to the next storyboard that we lose it.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are telling the view window to load a new root but what you want to be doing is have the UIBarTab open the other storyboard. Take a look at his post there is a very good detailed answer: [Proper Way to Open a New Storyboard through UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316406/proper-way-to-open-a-new-storyboard-through-uitabbarcontroller)